# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, stored-procedures

I am facing this error: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll but was not handled in user code .Additional information: The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure. Here is my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<abcProduct> GetAll()
{
    string cnn =
    "database connectionstring";
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "package_name.sp_name";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("resultset_out", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
        OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //rdr.Read();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            yield return new vProduct(GetNullableValue<string>(rdr["ABC_PRODUCT"]), GetNullableValue<string>(rdr["ABC_PRODUCT_AREA"]));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my store procedure structure

```
PROCEDURE PRC_ABC_PRODUCTS_GETALL(resultset_out OUTPUT TYPES.cursorType) AS

BEGIN
    OPEN resultset_out
    FOR

    SELECT UPPER(products.abc_product) abc_product,
        MAX(productareas.abc_product_area) abc_product_area
    FROM SCHEMA.AS_ABC_PRODUCT products
    LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.AS_ABC_PRODUCT_AREA productareas
        ON products.V_PRODUCT_AREA_ID = productareas.ABC_PRODUCT_AREA_ID
    WHERE products.VALID = 1
        AND products.abc_product NOT LIKE '$%'
    GROUP BY UPPER(products.abc_product),
        UPPER(productareas.abc_product_area)
    ORDER BY UPPER(products.ABC_PRODUCT);
END

PRC_ABC_PRODUCTS_GETALL;
```

Can anyone help on this? Can anybody point out what is the error?A little help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues in your code.

- It should be `cmd.CommandText = "PRC_ABC_PRODUCTS_GETALL";` instead of `cmd.CommandText = "package_name.sp_name";`
- `resultset_out OUTPUT TYPES.cursorType` is not valid Oracle Syntax. Should be `resultset_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR`. Were you able to compile the procedure?

Try it like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "begin res := PRC_ABC_PRODUCTS_GETALL; end;";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("res", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

and this PL/SQL:

```
FUNCTION PRC_ABC_PRODUCTS_GETALL RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
   resultset_out SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN resultset_out
    FOR

    SELECT UPPER(products.abc_product) abc_product,
        MAX(productareas.abc_product_area) abc_product_area
    FROM SCHEMA.AS_ABC_PRODUCT products
    LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.AS_ABC_PRODUCT_AREA productareas
        ON products.V_PRODUCT_AREA_ID = productareas.ABC_PRODUCT_AREA_ID
    WHERE products.VALID = 1
        AND products.abc_product NOT LIKE '$%'
    GROUP BY UPPER(products.abc_product),
        UPPER(productareas.abc_product_area)
    ORDER BY UPPER(products.ABC_PRODUCT);

    RETURN resultset_out;
END;
```

Comment: thanks for reply @Wernfried Domscheit :) . i can compile the sp in visual studio and it showed 0 errors but i haven't tried it yet with sql developer.I'm very much new to these things and these are all done by previous developer.Let me try this way :) and thanks once again for answering my question :)